# Mirth dicom sender error

Tags: mirth, dcm4che

I am trying to setup Mirth to route images based on the contents of a DICOM tag. I successfully set this up to forward to two different folders (i.e. if the specific tag contains this write to this folder, else write to this other folder). This was done using the 'filewriter' for the two destinations.

I have changed one of the destinations to a dicom sender and set it up to forward to a dcm4chee PACS. However, now when I send images I get the following error(where (ipaddress) is the address for the dcm4chee pacs the dicomsender should be routing to):

> DICOM Sender error ERROR MESSAGE: http://(ipaddress)/

DCMECHO to the pacs works fine. I have sent the same images directly to the PACS using a straight DCMSND from terminal and this is successful. I have sent images to Mirth and they are successfully routed to the other filewriter based on the rules included. I just cannot work out why the dicom sender isnt working. Any ideas? Anything I should look out for or check? The error logs in Mirth don't seem to be very informative.

Comment: What about the logs on the DCM4CHEE side? Maybe you will find any hints about the problem there.

Comment: Hmm its actually not getting as far as DCM4CHEE as there is nothing in the pacs log.

Comment: Why is there http:// before the IP address? Where does this come from? Did You enter any addresses with http protocol somewhere? Can You also perhaps export the entire channel and post it after anonymizing any addresses?

Comment: I am not sure why, I thought Mirth had added it in by default, but removing it seems to have solved the problem. Looks like Mirth was unable to find the host. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, well, the http most definetely has no place in a DICOM host address. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After helpful input from Tarmo R and jap1968, I discovered that the issue was being cause by a rogue 'http://' latched onto the beginning of the ip address. I think it must have appeared during copying/pasting between various sources. Anywho, deletion of this and leaving just the ip address solved the issue. 
Thanks for the help!